# Pass a value from parent page to popup to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield, popup

I have the following piece of code in a component

```
<apex:pageBlock id="Panel">
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Model.PAList}" var="pA">
         <apex:column width="28" rendered="{!AuthorModel.canAddDelA}" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pA.IsSelected__c}" onclick="SelectedA();"/>
             </apex:column>
```

**IsSelected__c is a field of the pA object.**

What I want to do is pass the ids of the selected pAs to a popup and from the popup once a button is clicked I want to pass it to a controller method. Can anyone explain me how to do that? I am relatively new in salesforce and any help would be appreciated.
The code for the popup is given below

```
<div class="attachModal" >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="mainDetail" title="Attach" >
            <div style="float: left; width: 70%;">
            <apex:form id="uploadAttach" >
                <table class="List">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="height: 58px;">
                            <td class="labelCol">............................
```

Comment: How do you open the pop up? Is it using the `onclick="SelectedA();"` js function? Can you pass the IDs as page params?

Comment: one option is to use the controller variables to manage state. As long as each user event involves an actionSupport or actionFunction, changes on the UI will transmit to the controller and hence be available to the popup